# Woocommerce - How to show Billing details email for non logged-in users on Thank You Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, for logged in users the Thankyou (order-received) page does show the customer details like the name, address and e-mail, but nothing when customers are not registered.

I found a workround for showing Billing details section, but Email is still hidden in the first overview section (Section above Order details) How to show email too, for non logged in user?

Comment: Are you using some kind of "guest checkout" plugin or function? Which one? In other words, how is the installation supposed to know the user's email address if the user isn't registered or logged in? When will they have supplied it?

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'adding_customers_details_to_thankyou', 10, 1 );
function adding_customers_details_to_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Only for non logged in users
    if ( ! $order_id ) return;

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id); // Get an instance of the WC_Order object

    wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-customer.php', array('order' => $order ));
}
```

You can check this code it will show up all details available for guest user on thank you page add this code in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

[image]

So in woocommerce plugin download the current thankyou.php file and remove is_user_logged_in() from the line for getting email to be displayed for guest users 
[image]

Tested and Worked

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uzelPFp I want to show email ID in the Top overview section. I already did this code for showing billing details.

Comment: I have edited the code and have been tested  and working great